# What was the ocean circulation like during the time of Pangaea?

Tags: oceanography, paleoclimatology, paleogeography, thermohaline-circulation

So [Enderton and Marshall](http://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/52333) (2009) wrote an interesting paper on the ocean circulation of various aquaplanets covered with certain terrain: e.g. an aquaplanet with a small ridge of land that ranged from North Pole to South Pole, and studied the effects it had on the ocean circulation.

I'm curious: Has anyone ever applied this type of analysis to a Pangaea-like planet?

Answer (score 16):

Here is an estimate from Beauchamp and Baud (2002), for parts of the ocean around Pangea, for the latter parts of it's existence (~300-250mya). It is based on various previous papers that looked at deposits of carbonates and phosphate deposits, and made a few assumptions, including a sufficient supply of silica and nutrient inputs, and environments suitable for particular biota, including particularly siliceous sponges:

[image: Ocean circulation patterns for]

- Beauchamp, B. & Baud, A., 2002. Growth and demise of Permian biogenic chert along northwest Pangea: evidence for end-Permian collapse of thermohaline circulation. Palaeogeography, Palaeoclimatology, Palaeoecology, 184(1–2), pp.37–63. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031018202002456